# Determine camera pose?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, perspectivecamera

I am trying to determine camera pose based on fiducial marker found in a scene.

Fiducial: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=4r6k3q&s=8#.VNLnWTVVK1E

**Current process:**

1. Use SIFT for feature detection
2. Use SIFT for descriptor extraction
3. Use FLANN for matching
4. Find the homography using CV_RANSAC
5. Identify the corners of the fiducial
6. Identify corners of the fiducial in the scene using perspectiveTransform()
7. Draw lines around corners (i.e. prove that it found the fiducial in the scene
8. Run camera calibration
9. Load calibration results (cameraMatrix & distortionCoefficients)

Now I am trying to figure out the camera pose.
I attempted to use:

void solvePnP(const Mat& objectPoints, const Mat& 
    imagePoints, const Mat& cameraMatrix, const Mat& distCoeffs,
    Mat& rvec, Mat& tvec, bool useExtrinsicGuess=false)

where:

- obectPoints are the fiducial corners
- imagePoints are the fiducial corners in the scene
- cameraMatrix is from calibration
- distCoeffs is from calibration
- rvec and tvec should be returned to me from this function

However, when I run this, I get a core dump error, so I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

I haven't found very good documentation on solvePNP() - did I misunderstand the function or input parameters?

Appreciate your help

***Update***
Here is my process:

```
OrbFeatureDetector detector; //Orb seems more accurate than SIFT
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2; 

detector.detect(marker_im, keypoints1);
detector.detect(scene_im, keypoints2);

Mat display_marker_im, display_scene_im;
drawKeypoints(marker_im, keypoints1, display_marker_im, Scalar(0,0,255));
drawKeypoints(scene_im, keypoints2, display_scene_im, Scalar(0,0,255));

SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;

extractor.compute( marker_im, keypoints1, descriptors1 );
extractor.compute( scene_im, keypoints2, descriptors2 );

BFMatcher matcher; //BF seems to match better than FLANN
vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors1, descriptors2, matches );

Mat img_matches;
drawMatches( marker_im, keypoints1, scene_im, keypoints2,
    matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
    vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

vector<Point2f> obj, scene;
for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
    obj.push_back(keypoints1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
    scene.push_back(keypoints2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
}

Mat H;
H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

//Get corners of fiducial
vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
obj_corners[1] = cvPoint(marker_im.cols, 0);
obj_corners[2] = cvPoint(marker_im.cols, marker_im.rows);
obj_corners[3] = cvPoint(0, marker_im.rows);
vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

FileStorage fs2("cal.xml", FileStorage::READ);

Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;
fs2["Camera_Matrix"] >> cameraMatrix;
fs2["Distortion_Coefficients"] >> distCoeffs;

Mat rvec, tvec;

//same points as object_corners, just adding z-axis (0)
vector<Point3f> objp(4);
objp[0] = cvPoint3D32f(0,0,0);
objp[1] = cvPoint3D32f(gray.cols, 0, 0);
objp[2] = cvPoint3D32f(gray.cols, gray.rows, 0);
objp[3] = cvPoint3D32f(0, gray.rows, 0);

solvePnPRansac(objp, scene_corners, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec );

Mat rotation, viewMatrix(4, 4, CV_64F);
Rodrigues(rvec, rotation);

for(int row=0; row<3; ++row)
{
   for(int col=0; col<3; ++col)
   {
      viewMatrix.at<double>(row, col) = rotation.at<double>(row, col);
   }
   viewMatrix.at<double>(row, 3) = tvec.at<double>(row, 0);
}

viewMatrix.at<double>(3, 3) = 1.0f;

cout << "rotation: " << rotation << endl;
cout << "viewMatrix: " << viewMatrix << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so `solvePnP()` gives you the transfer matrix from the model's frame (ie the cube) to the camera's frame (it's called view matrix).

Input parameters:

- `objectPoints` – Array of object points in the object coordinate space, 3xN/Nx3 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 3-channel, where N is the number of points. `std::vector<cv::Point3f>` can be also passed here. The points are 3D, but since they are in a pattern coordinate system (of the fiducial marker), then the rig is planar so that Z-coordinate of each input object point is 0,
- `imagePoints` – Array of corresponding image points, 2xN/Nx2 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 2-channel, where N is the number of points. `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` can be also passed here,
- `intrinsics`: camera matrix (focal length, principal point),
- `distortion`: distortion coefficients, zero distortion coefficients are assumed if it is empty,
- `rvec`: output rotation vector
- `tvec`: output translation vector

Building of the view matrix is something like this:

```
cv::Mat rvec, tvec;
cv::solvePnP(objectPoints, imagePoints, intrinsics, distortion, rvec, tvec);
cv::Mat rotation, viewMatrix(4, 4, CV_64F);
cv::Rodrigues(rvec, rotation);

for(int row=0; row<3; ++row)
{
   for(int col=0; col<3; ++col)
   {
      viewMatrix.at<double>(row, col) = rotation.at<double>(row, col);
   }

   viewMatrix.at<double>(row, 3) = tvec.at<double>(row, 0);
}

viewMatrix.at<double>(3, 3) = 1.0f;
```

Furthermore, can you share your code and error message?

Comment: That finds extrinsic parameters of calibration chessboard. I was trying to find the camera pose based on fiducial marker. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Kornel - so if I want to find the (xyz) position the camera relative to the fiducial, I would take the fiducial xyz, rotate based on the rotation matrix, and then translate?

Comment: Sorry for being late in answering you. So for pose estimation you should have a calibration pattern with known 3D geometry and position on the image plane (e.g. your fiducial pattern). `cv::solvePnP()` will find the object pose desired from 3D-2D point correspondences so this function's output (`rvecs` and `tvecs`) brings points from the model coordinate system to the camera coordinate system. If you want to find the camera relative position to the fiducial pattern you should invert the transformation.

Comment: and one other thing, in your case is the position of the pattern fix, and is the camera floating around it?

Comment: Floating camera around fixed pattern

Comment: So, Rodrigues(rotation.t(), rvecCam) and tvecCam = -rotation.t()*tvec get me the camera position and rotation relative to the fiducial? If so, the values being returned don't hold water. I've double checked my calibration